# PodでRealmがインストールできない

Tags: swift, realm

podからRealmSwiftをインストールする際に以下のエラーが出てインストールできません。

Swift 3.0
pod 1.2.1

*podfile*

```
target 'realmTester' do
use_frameworks!
  pod ‘RealmSwift’

end
```

$pod install

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Realm (2.6.2)

[!] /bin/bash -c
set -e
sh build.sh cocoapods-setup

core is not a symlink. Deleting...
Downloading dependency: sync 1.5.2
tar (child): xz: exec 不能: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

どなたか直し方を教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: Realmのコアライブラリのダウンロードに失敗しています。先ほど私の環境で確認してみると問題なく完了したので、ネットワーク環境の良いところで再度やってみたらいかがでしょうか？

Comment: CocoaPodsの場合はスマートクォートの機能で意図せず`‘...’`となってしまうことが考慮されているので、このように書いても問題なく動きます（警告は出ますが）。そのため、今回のインストールが失敗する原因ではありません。

Answer (score -2):

```
pod ‘RealmSwift’
```

の「‘」を「'」に変えてみてはどうですか

Comment: CocoaPodsの場合はスマートクォートの機能で意図せず`‘...’`となってしまうことが考慮されているので、このように書‌​いても問題なく動きます（警告は出ますが）‌​。そのため、今回のインストールが失敗する原因では‌​ありません。